# How to figure out identifier of input fields from external pop up window

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to put username and password to pop up window. The trouble is that this is some kind of modal or some external window where I can´t find any xpath, id etc... element how to identify this fields. I have came through all topics regarding this but non of them helped me in Java for cucumber/selenium.

Using "https://username:password@wedomain.cz/" doesn´t work.

Using code like this:

```
WebElement email_id = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Uživatelské 
jméno"));
        email_id.sendKeys("XXX");
        WebElement password_id = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Heslo"));
        password_id.sendKeys("xxx");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement sign = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Přihlaste se"));
        sign.click();
```

Doesn´t work. I must also say that domain I go to is different from domain I see on security pop up window.

[image]

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: @MartinF : It seems that the Pop up is a windows Pop up, which can not be handled by selenium though we have some workaround for that such as Robot class of java or autoIt ot sikuli

Comment: @Kajal Kundu Application is written in Angular 7 so it is SPA so this doesn´t have background classic html page...sorry.

Comment: @Pritam Maske So probably to look for Robot class of java implementation somewhere in google, right? :-)

Comment: @MartinF : refer this  https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html

Comment: @PritamMaske thanks, thats what I am just looking at. I am struggle to how construct word from keyEvent, like write "word" robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_w), robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_o);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_r);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_d);
.... I will google it. Anyway thansk a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION - need to be done with robot class or another automation library.

https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html

Closing question.